# Can Space Solar Farms be Created?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

I fancy that, the earth's magnetic field being like a donut, solar energy farms could be placed over the poles, and that electricity could be conducted to the poles and fed into the grid or, (less ideally) laser light could be beamed to the pole and converted into electricity and fed into the grid. This would operate 24/7, as it could have continuous exposure without reorientation.

Would the magnetic 'funnel' at each of the poles channel electricity or a laser beam, and in the case of the latter, in such an electro-magnetic environment, could electricity be induced to ride it to the earth's surface?

Comment: Why don't you comment on the theoretical problem at the heart of this post, which is; can a giga-watt current of electricity possibly be conducted along a laser beam in the polar electromagnetic environment?  If not, can electricity be conducted along, rather than through a physical conductor from a polar space platform to the earth?  It is a problem that only exists in these unique conditions.  If you can pose it as a purely theoretical problem, do that for me rather than seek to have my post removed as 'inappropriate', snobs.

Answer (score 0):

I think your ideas is that if solar units could hover over the poles they would have continuous sunlight.  While that is true, keeping solar farms in space over the poles would be very difficult, since in order to stay in orbit the solar units would need to move in orbits around the earth. See [polar orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_orbit).

Maybe your idea is that the solar units could be magnetic, and oriented in such a way that the Earth's field would repel them and keep them hovering.  Unfortunately the Earth's field is much too weak for that.

The good news is that if there were three or more solar farms spaced out evenly along an equatorial orbit, at least two would be in full sunlight at any moment.

Comment: My idea is the solar farms should not orbit, but be stationed over the poles, moving with them as they slowly oscillate.  The force of gravity is not that strong and can be counteracted by using some of the energy that is being created to maintain both position over the pole and altitude.

Comment: I wish that were true.

Comment: Do you know that it couldn't be?

Comment: This is not the place for an extended discussion.  But I'd suggest you do some reading and some detailed thinking about what the forces are, what the available power/per/mass would be, and how the captured solar energy might be used to produce thrust.

Comment: I'm sure someone, not me, can boil those issues down to a paragraph.

There are other interesting aspects of the concept. For instance, earth-based solar panels need to have robust construction, whereas space based panels could consist of rolls of photovoltaic material applied to a grid base. That means large expanses of it could be put into space.

The real catch however is whether it is possible to beam electricity up to 500 miles through space and the earth's atmosphere. Alternately, a 'lightning rod' set-up could work like conducting motor oil down a stick into your car motor.

Comment: That also describes the question about the laser beam; could it act as a 'lightning rod' for an artificial lightning bolt?